# Using ParentDecorator class for Child classes

Tags: java, design-patterns

Lets say I have four classes:

```
abstract class Parent {/*do stuff*/ }

class ChildA extends Parent {/*do more stuff*/}

class ChildB extends Parent {/*do more stuff differently*/}

class ParentDecorator extends Parent { 
  // do stuff
  doSomething() {
    //doing something
  }
```

}

How can i use ParentDecorator method doSomething() with ChildA and ChildB objects? 
The obvious answer would be something like:

```
Parent child = new ParentDecorator(child);
((ParentDecorator) child).doSomething();
```

but my case, all my objects are in a lists like:

```
ArrayList<Parent> objects;
```

and i have methods like `findObject(info)` which returns an object from the list.

Now, lets say i want to call doStuff from the decorator for a specific object from that list. I can do something like:

```
Parent child1 = findObject(info);
child1 = new ParentDecorator(child1);
((ParentDecorator) child1).doSomething();
```

but with this, only child1 will be able to use ParentDecorator functionality, and findObject(info) will return an unchanged object.
I tried this:

```
( (ParentDecorator) findObject(info)).doSomething();
```

but it throws an error "ChildA cannot be cast to ParentDecorator"

Do i need to creat ChildADecorator and ChildBDecorator, which seems a bit redundant? Or is there some workaround i cant seem to figure out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized i could simply do this:

```
Parent child1 = findObject(info);
child1 = new ParentDecorator(child1);
objects.remove(child1); //remove child1 from the object list
((ParentDecorator) child1).doSomething();
objects.add(child1);  //add it again
```

not the most elegant solution, but it will do